# Adjust rate limit of a running pipe viewer (pv) process

Tags: bash, pipe, bandwidth

I am using pipe viewer (pv) to limit the transfer rate while uploading VM backups to an online storage. Here is how I use it in a bash script:

```
ssh root@xenserver "xe vm-export uuid=${CurrentSnapshotUUID} filename=" | ${gpgEncrypt} | pv --quiet --rate-limit 300k | /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp - ${bucketS3}/${CurrentVM}_${TodayDate}.xva.gpg
```

This works like a charm, but I have a limitation that I cannot upload with 300 KByte/s during peak time. This causes excessive traffic which is pretty expensive.
Unfortunately, I cannot split the data into several parts and upload them one after the other. It's one huge data stream generated by the vm export that I need to process in one go. And I need to find a way to lower the rate limit at a certain time without interrupting pv.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andrew Wood, the author of pv, I found the answer to my question. You can change the rate limit of a remote pv session with PID 123 like this:

```
pv --remote 123 --rate-limit 200k
```

What a cool feature. Case closed!